# In a chain of $.ajax().done() calls, can I transform data for next .done()?

Tags: ajax, typescript, transform, chaining

I've got an existing api routine that I'd like to insert transform before the next `.done()` gets called. In my case it a simple extra level of `JSON.parse()` that needs to occur but the wider question is can I do anything to the response data that the next `.done()` will be able to see?

so take this api :

```
function foo(){
   return $.ajax( ... )
           .done(data=> {  .. do something with the data here ...});
}
```

and the caller can see this:

```
foo().done(data=>{ .. transformed data visible here ... });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `ajax` returns a `Deferred` object, which is (now) a promise per the Promises/A+ specification. So you could switch to using `then`, which has the semantics you're looking for:

```
function foo(){
   return $.ajax( ... )
           .then(data => {
               return /*...the transformed data...*/;
           });
}
```

then:

```
foo().then(data => { /*.. transformed data visible here ...*/ });
```

**Note:** If the code calling `foo` can't be changed, no worries; `done` will see the updated data, too. But it has to be `then` *within* `foo`. Switch to `then` in the code calling `foo` too if you can, but if you can't, it's fine.

Here's a live example using `then` within `foo` and `done` when calling it: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/y1zh2xL4/

```
function foo(){
    return $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {
            json: '{"key":"value"}',
            delay: 1
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        return {key: data.key.toUpperCase()};
    });
}

// Just to show that `done` sees the updated data
foo().done(data => { console.log(data); });
```

In a comment you asked:

> Further question; is there a way to do the same sort of transform in an error chain?

Yup! Promises are designed such that the two paths can be transformed at each level. To transform the rejection passing through the chain, you either return a rejected promise (`return Promise.reject(x)`) or throw (`throw x`). `x` can be anything you want, although by convention it's usually an `Error` object.

So for instance (https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/y1zh2xL4/1/):

```
function foo(){
    return $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/echo/bad-url-not-on-jsfiddle",
        data: {
            json: '{"key":"value"}',
            delay: 1
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        return {key: data.key.toUpperCase()};
    })
    .catch(error => {
        const myError = new Error("ajax failed");
        myError.originalError = error;
        myError.otherInformation = "whatever";
        throw myError;
    });
}

foo()
.done(data => { console.log(data); })
.fail(error => {
    console.error(error);
    console.error(error.otherInformation);
});
```

Comment: Further question; is there a way to do the same sort of transform in an error chain?
eg. `foo().done(..success..).fail(data=>{ transformed data here..})`

I found that a regular return from with the error part of a then caused the `.done()` to trigger as though it were successful. If I `throw data` then it triggers the `.fail()` but doesn't include the data.

Comment: @Petebr - Yup, promise chains let you do that too. :-) I've added an example. (For what it's worth, I go into promises in some detail in Chapter 8 of my new book; see my profile for details.)

Comment: I see, I was missing the `new Error()` construct when throwing it.

Comment: @Petebr - Huh, I wouldn't think that was fundamentally required by `done`/`fail` (it isn't by `then`/`catch`). It is best practice, but not required...

Comment: You're right, it wasn't actually required. I introduced a new and subtle error with `throw` inside `try ... catch` which of course caught itself!